# Using python-gnupg library in AWS lambda function

Tags: python, encryption

I'm using Python 3.12 in an AWS Lambda function to decrypt PGP encrypted files. I'm using the `python-gnupg` version 0.6.0 library to do this. It decrypts files fine on my development Mac but fails when run in the AWS environment. I figured out this makes sense because the `python-gnupg` library is a wrapper around the system level GnuPG binaries. These exist on my Mac but aren't present in the AWS execution environment of the lambda function.

Does anyone have suggestions, ideas or pointers how I might go about solving this problem?